# Remove Qt Webkit loading cursor while loading

Tags: c++, qt

I have a window with the `QWebView` and when I try to load a page from the resource (qrc), the Window keeps like frozen and the cursor loading until it finishes loading.

If you look at the browsers this does not happen, the cursor remains normal and the page loads, but with the `QWebView` it's different.

Is it possible to change that?

(you cannot see the loading cursor on the screenshot)

[image: Window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it adding a slot to `loadFinished` signal of `QWebView` with the `show` method of the window and removed the `show` method of the `main.cpp` file, this way the `MainWindow` will be created but will show only when the `QWebView` loads the page.